# Extract List with ExtractVariables & JSONPath from JSON

Tags: apigee

I'm trying to extract a list from a JSON response and put it inside a variable so that I can later put this list as a claim in my custom generated JWT with `GenerateJWT`.

My current problem is that I'm always ending up with a stringified array as a string.

**ExtractVariables**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="true" enabled="true" name="ExtractResponse">
    ...
    <JSONPayload>
        <Variable name="sysRoles">
            <JSONPath>$.sysRoles</JSONPath>
        </Variable>
    </JSONPayload>
    ...
</ExtractVariables>
```

**GenerateJWT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GenerateJWT async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="GenerateJWT">
    ...
    <AdditionalClaims>
        <Claim name="sysRoles" ref="sysRoles" wantFaultIfUnresolved="false"/>
    </AdditionalClaims>
    ...
</GenerateJWT>
```

The claim in my token is always a string: `"sysRoles": "[\"something\",\"something-other\"]"`.

What I also tried and did not work out:

1. using `type` and `array` on the extraction: `<Variable name="sysRoles" type="string" array="true">` (puts the stringifyed list into an actual list)
2. using `type` and `array` on the JWT generation: `<Claim name="sysRoles" ref="sysRoles" wantFaultIfUnresolved="false" type="string" array="true"/>` (also puts the stringifyed list into an actual list)
3. using asterisk on the JSONPath: `<JSONPath>$.sysRoles[*]</JSONPath>` (no changes)

**What is the correct way to do this without having some intermediate step doing some JS logic?**

**Edit** actual problem is in the claim generation. The extracted variable is indeed a list of strings, but the claim always ends up with the stringifyed list.